# How to parse MultiDimension Json Array into CSV using json.JSONArray

Tags: java, csv, export-to-csv, json

Here is my Json response:

```
{
"value": [
    {
        "type": "school",
        "id": 12,
        "name": "NNPS",
        "city": "CA",
        "geo_position": {
            "latitude": 52.52437,
            "longitude": 13.41053
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "College",
        "id": 44,
        "name": "PEC",
        "city": "PE",
        "geo_position": {
            "latitude": 45.50298,
            "longitude": 10.04366
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is my java code using "json.JSONArray" library:

```
while ((csvdata= br.readLine()) != null) {
  JSONObject output= new JSONObject(csvdata);
  JSONArray docs = output.getJSONArray("value");
  String csv = CDL.toString(docs);
  FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, csv);
 }
```

When i checked `csv` file, it shows me like this:

[image]
    **But it should be like this:**

[image]
I am at very beginning of my coding stage and currently improving it. Please give me some advice on it :)
How should i change it?

Comment: Why should it be like that?  What have you done to cause that transformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the level of lat and long again. This worked for me

```
while ((csvdata= br.readLine()) != null) {
   JSONObject output= new JSONObject(csvdata);
   JSONArray docs = output.getJSONArray("value");

   for(int i=0; i<docs.length();i++){
       JSONObject geo_pos =  (JSONObject)(docs.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("geo_position"));
       docs.getJSONObject(i).put("latitude", geo_pos.get("latitude"));
       docs.getJSONObject(i).put("longitude", geo_pos.get("longitude"));
       docs.getJSONObject(i).remove("geo_position");
   }       

   String csv = CDL.toString(docs);
   FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, csv);
 }
```

Comment: I tried this approach. For keys with null values, I couldn't get a column in final response.